# Does current sensing amplifiers output the voltage read multiplied by its gain to the out pin?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I would like to use a current sensing amplifier [INA180](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809251712_Texas-Instruments-INA180A4IDBVT_C133969.pdf) and i would like to make sure i understood it correctly.

I will be reading current upto 10A and would hopefully want to read at 0.01A of resolution, the adc is inbuilt with the microcontroller 12bits resolution and i would like to use the 1v reference. So i should be able to read 1v/4096 = 0.0002v increments on the microcontroller.

The INA180 will be Supplied with 3.3v, and the Rsense is 0.0005 ohms.

So will the INA180 spit out the voltage read on the Rsense (multiplied by its gain)? For example, a 0.01A on the 0.0005 ohms should read a voltage of V=I*R or 0.000005v so that would mean a gain of 200 would spit out 0.001v, the adc has ample of precision to spare and also at 10A it would spit out 1v

Am i correct?

Comment: which mcu has 1v adc reference?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič the SAMD21 series, am still prototyping and currently will be using the arduino zero as a dev board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated gains on the data sheet are for input to output hence 10 mA through 0.5 mΩ produces a voltage of 5 μV across the sense resistor. This might be amplified 200 times by the A4 device resulting in an output voltage of 1 mV.

> *Am i correct?*

Yes. But a problem might lie in the input offset voltage of (worst-case) +/- 500 μV DC. This will add-to or subtract-from your 5 μV input voltage and basically undermine the accuracy of any low-level DC you want to monitor.

The Common-mode rejection ratio (CMRR) will also cause significant issues if the supply voltage that you are monitoring for current moves around a bit. CMRR is typically 100 dB and this means that 1 volt of ripple on the supply you are monitoring will produce 10 μV of equivalent input ripple. This is added to your real signal.

It sounds to me like you might be expecting too much with such a low value shunt resistor.

Comment: Great ! another thing, is using a sense resistor with that low of a resistance common? im worried that it will greatly affect the accuracy of the reading (assuming the resistors true value is as stated). And it might be better to choose a higher value resistor and reduce the gain. If im able to have +- 0.01a or 0.02a accuracy on the final reading i would be happy. But then the adc perfomance also must be taken into consideration.

Comment: Added a few words to my answer.

Comment: Well thats really complicates things. looks like my +-0.01a accuracy is just impossible, because to have a +- 0.01A accuracy, the resistor i must use is 0.05ohms and with the full 10A i would need to use a resistor that is atleast 5W rated, although its not impossible to do this i need to have a higher rating than that for it to last, i really need to look for a better current amplifier with lower offset

Comment: It can be a difficult problem to solve @DrakeJest and hall-effect sensors do not produce an improvement in accuracy either. The only real possibility is to use a floated op-amp and resistor sensor and ADC combined. I've seen this done before but it's more complex than what you envisaged. You'd need an isolating DC-to-DC converter, a very decent op-amp and a serial ADC plus, you'd need an isolating digital buffer (available from ADI e.g.) to control the ADC and get data from it.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, practically it has some limitations. The input offset voltage is max. \$\pm500\mu V\$ (worst case scenario) with a gain of 200 this gives \$\pm 0.1V\$. The maximum VSN Swing to GND is \$5mV\$ (worst case). So in the worst case you get 0.15V of dead band at low curent measurement that can give you that current below 0.15A won't be detected.